# Some tags that need fixing

Tags: bug

- [ethernet-sheild](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethernet-sheild): Misspelled. It should be renamed to ethernet-shield since there is no existing tag of that name.
- [intterupt](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/intterupt): Misspelled. Should be deleted because there is already an [interrupt](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interrupt) tag and there are no questions using the intterupt tag.
- [edison](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edison): It was [decided](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/using-board-names-as-tags) that all board names should be prepended by arduino-. There is no arduino-edison tag, so this should be renamed arduino-edison, similar to [arduino-galileo](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arduino-galileo).

Comment: You are drastically misrepresenting the linked question about board naming - in addition to the fact that nothing was "decided" the arguments there apply only to *some* of the boards which officially have Arduino as the leading part of their name.  But there is no such thing as an Arduino-Edison (or an arduino-esp8266 or an arduino-teensy-3.2, etc).  Since questions that aren't about Arduino are off-topic, there's no need to invent fake names to emphasize in the tag that an arduino approach is being used - if it isn't, the question gets closed as off topic

Comment: Chris, it's listed on the [Arduino products page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/ArduinoCertified/IntelEdison) so in a sense it is associated with Arduino. However it is "certified" rather than being an Arduino product. The arguments listed in the link in the question about not prepending Arduino (eg. arduino-robot) would seem to apply here as well. Edison on its own has other meanings.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, I'm hoping to get other opinions. So far we have one for and one against. :)

Comment: Related: https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2370/is-an-esp8266-running-arduino-code-question-allowed

Comment: I only would suggest that the edison tag be consistent with galileo, however that is to be done. intel-edison would be another option. I really don't have a strong opinion on the topic. I actually didn't realize that, unlike the 101, those boards weren't really branded as Arduino even though they are Arduino certified. My original motivation for this post was to get the ethernet-sheild spelling fixed but I thought I might as well review all the tags while I was at it.

Comment: Personally I don't care either way what is done with the edison tag. It can be deleted for all I care, since the edison itself has been discontinued and only three people ever bought them anyway.

Comment: `intel-edison` is something that used to exist.  `arduino-edison` is not - the product was the Intel Edison *for* Arduino.

Comment: I'm happy with changing [tag:edison] to `intel-edison` and changing [tag:arduino-galileo] to `intel-galileo`.

Comment: I like the `intel-edison` and `intel-galileo` suggestion above.

Answer (score 3):

- I fixed the ethernet-sheild tag.
- The intterupt tag will apparently be deleted at midnight as part of an automatic cleanup of tags which don't have any questions associated with them.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please review the tag synonyms while you are adjusting the tags.

https://arduino.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest

It's not easy to find the suggested tag synonyms - there is no review queue for it (that I know of). To get to it you have to go `Tags` > scroll to the bottom of the page > `tag synonyms` > `suggested`. Its not too obvious.